# How to Write a driverkit extension for Mac OS catalina

Tags: macos-catalina, driverkit, macos-system-extension

I am trying to write a driver kit extension for one of devices. I have not got Information on How to write a driverkit extension for mac os Catalina.
The only Documentation which I got is

DriverKit Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit?language=objc

& the WWDC Video:  https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/702/

Is there a Sample on how to Write a driver Kit extension and a System extension for installing it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't come across one yet, unfortunately. I'm working on one though.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/knightsc/USBApp. This is the only example i could find. Have u referred the same or something else

Comment: Mostly just trial and error. I'm still in the process of porting my first driver to DriverKit, but I'm writing a guide based on my experiences.

Comment: It would be helpful if u share the guide once you complete that. meanwhile, I will share my experiences if I succeed.

Comment: hi, I am able to compile this and  changed the code  and the plist to load my device. when I am trying to load that I am getting a dialog just like kext approval. but nothing happens after that. there are no os log , I can see that my device in ioreg but it only shows. it only shows
                    !registered, !matched, active                                                                                     my os logs are not coming. How to proceed after that

Answer (score 1):

Apple finally added two examples of [HIDDriverkit DEXTs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/hiddriverkit) and companion applications on Dec 16 2020.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to open the device with exclusive access and perform Device IO, you may not need to write the Driver Kit driver. Instead, you can use IOUSBHost framework

[Info on using the IOUSBHost framework](https://tejusadiga.wordpress.com/2020/06/06/time-to-farewell-kernel-extensions-kext-on-macos/)